# Replace a line with another line using IF - Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to replace a line in load.xml using the lines read from FileList.txt.
Contents of load.xml

```
<mainheader>
        <InFilePath>D:\Data\All_Inputfiles\oldfile.txt</InFilePath>
</mainheader>
```

FileList.txt

```
 newfile1.txt
 newfile2.txt
```

Expecting the output with each iteration as

```
   <mainheader>
            <InFilePath>D:\Data\All_Inputfiles\newfile1.txt</InFilePath>
    </mainheader>
```

and with the next iteration replace newfile1.txt with newfile2.txt. I am able to get original string with the final string but last part of the code is throwing syntax error, i.e. from 
for /f "delims=" %%a in (!INTEXTFILE!) do call :Change "%%a"  .

Could please help me?
Thanks in advance.

```
    @echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
Set AllInputFile= D:\data\FileList.txt
SET INTEXTFILE=C:\c:\load.xml
set OUTTEXTFILE=D:\data\tmp_out.txt
SET BackupPath=D:\data\backupload.xml
Set TempFile=D:\data\tmp.txt
SET DbgFile=D:\data\debuginfo.txt
 Del !TempFile!
 Del !DbgFile!
 Copy !INTEXTFILE! !BackupPath!
:replace
   findstr /g "InFilePath" !INTEXTFILE!>!TempFile!
   :: set string="        <InFilePath>D:\Data\All_Inputfiles\oldfile.txt</InFilePath>" 
   set /p string=< !TempFile!
   SET PREVFILE_NM=!string:~75,-13!       
  set FinalreplaceLine=!string!  
  set TARG_FILE=%~1
  REM ECHO  "Before Replace FinalreplaceLine "!FinalreplaceLine!>>!DbgFile!
   set FinalreplaceLine=!FinalreplaceLine:%PREVFILE_NM%=%TARG_FILE%! 
   ECHO  "string "!string!>>!DbgFile!
  ECHO  "FinalreplaceLine "!FinalreplaceLine!>>!DbgFile!


  ::string has source string and FinalreplaceLine has target string to replace
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (!INTEXTFILE!) do call :Change "%%a"  
  exit /b

  :Change
  set Text=%~1
   if "%Text%"=="%string%" (
    (echo !FinalreplaceLine!)>> !OUTTEXTFILE!
     ) else (
     (echo !Text!)>> !OUTTEXTFILE!
       )
    exit /b
```

Comment: Do you want only those three lines in load.xml - and after something launches you want to update the file, repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("FileList.txt") do (
   call :change "%%a"
   type "load.xml"
   pause
)
echo done
pause
goto :EOF
:change
(
echo ^<mainheader^>
echo        ^<InFilePath^>D:\Data\All_Inputfiles\%~1^</InFilePath^>
echo ^</mainheader^>
) > "load.xml"
```